# Using numeric values in switch statements

Tags: r, switch-statement

I'm trying to use numeric values in a switch statement. However, as shown in this snippet, this does not work with my approach:

```
x <- as.character(1)
switch(x,
  x = "case 1",
  "default"
)
# "default"
```

What I'm expecting is this behavior:

```
switch("1",
  "1" = "case 1",
  "default"
)
# "case 1"
```

I'm confused by this, because I can't tell where the two approaches deviate, since this suggests they should work the same:

```
as.character(1) == "1"
# TRUE
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: switch in R is not like switch in C.  Also you are using an assignment operator rather than a comparison operator. But neither will work for what I think you are trying to do. Read [this](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/switch-function/) for more.

Answer (score 1):

From `help(switch)`:

> If ‘EXPR’ evaluates to a character string then that string is
> matched (exactly) to the names of the elements in ‘...’.

So in your first case, the string "1" is matched to the string "x" (the *name* of the first element). That does not match, hence going to default.